# Paypal Checkout : make API call after successful payment

Tags: angular, paypal, checkout

I am using PayPal checkout for my angular 4 project.I want to make an API call after PayPal payment gets success, but `actions.payment.execute().then` not allowed to access any outside object.

Can I get any event for successful  ??

---

```
onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {

    return actions.payment.execute().then(function () {
      //want to make an api call
                    });
                }
        }, '#paypal-button-container');
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer here [Processing Paypal onAuthorize callback in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861004/processing-paypal-onauthorize-callback-in-angular-4), you can dispatch CustomEvent:

```
document.querySelector('#paypal-button').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('onPaymentCompleted', { detail: {payment: JSON.stringify(payment)},bubbles: true }));
```

on Paypal buttom:

```
<div id="paypal-button" (onPaymentCompleted)="addNewContract($event)"></div>
```

and then you have an access to original context again:

```
addNewContract(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.payment);
    }
```