# Processing Paypal onAuthorize callback in Angular 4

Tags: angular, paypal, checkout

I can successfully load checkout.js in Angular 4 app, render the Paypal button, the new window appears, I confirm the payment, the payment is processed but I do not know how to setup onAuthorize callback to process the response in Angular 4 (like to show the success and store a payment record to MongoDb). Here is my code. I can see the first console.log containing the payment response but I cannot access the component's scope, so nothing after this first console.log is executed. I get no error in console. Even the console.log("successful!") is not processed.

```
onAuthorize: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {
                console.log("response = " + JSON.stringify(payment));
                this._alertService.success("The extension of subscription was succesfull!");
                this.user.contracts.push({
                        "acquired": new Date(payment.create_time), 
                        "price": payment.transactions[0].amount.total, 
                        "expires": new Date(this.user.expires.getFullYear()+this.selectedAccountExtensionOption.addedYears, this.user.expires.getMonth(), this.user.expires.getDate()) 
                        });
                console.log("successful!");     

            });
        },
```

Comment: Care to share your integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that context (`this`) is not available in callback. The best solution would be to bind `this` as explained in [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Alternative solution is to emit custom event in PayPal callback (documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events))

`let event = new CustomEvent('dosomething', { data: "some data" });`

and then catch this event in your component. Documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener).

```
@HostListener('dosomething') 
onDoSomething(data) {
 console.log(data)
 // your rest of the implementation
}
```